# Raspberry Pi 2 vs STM32f429I Discovery?

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, stm32f4

I couldn't really figure out this issue. Raspberry Pi 2 has 1GB of RAM, 900 Mhz Quad Core ARM Cortex-A7 processor and so on. On the other side we have Cortex-4 processor 256Kb RAM. Other peripherals also points to Raspberry pi. However they have almost the same price.

Please do not judge me, because I think I am missing some point here and I think there is a reason it is so. Can someone enlighten me in this topic please?

Comment: 1) You are comparing potatoes to oranges. 2) Have you heard about price formation?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, I have not. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I also know that they have different purposes and I use them both currently. My question is about the hardware and price in general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RPi is a full-featured, ready-to-use product. It is mass-produced and used widely mostly by individuals. Contrary, Discovery boards , as many of other evaluation boards are *development tools* used, as named, for evaluation of a specific technology in order to make *another* product, potentially with much lower cost. Being a tool, it is produced in much lower volumes and targeting mostly companies rather than individuals. So the volume and the target consumers are the factors setting the price.

Comment: That makes a lot sense. It would be fortunate if there was a   cheap general purpose Cortex-M4 board ready to use as product, though.

Comment: @ozgur Tiva C Launchpad is very affordable. But it has no periferals, if you might need some..

Comment: That is absolutely beautiful. There is no documentation about license issues. Do you think it is available to use in commercial products?

Comment: @ozgur I don't think there would be licensing problem. There is another problem with using eval boards with commercial product - you have no guarantees of their life time and stocks. They can be discontinued without a notice.

Comment: Yep, I am aware of that. This is a one time project. Only 80-90 devices will suffice. Thank you for all the information. I appreciate.

Comment: Before committing to a board using TI Stellaris processor, be sure to read the errata.  Quite a few advertised features of TI's Cortex M are not actually usable.  (Particularly annoying because they haven't removed the non-functional capabilities from the parametric search -- or hadn't, when I ran into this problem)

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit further than Eugene's answer of price being dependent on manufacture quantity, which is very astute and correct (100's of thousands RPi vs 1000's at best of Experimenter boards per edition),

There is a big difference in the application of a Cortex-M series core and a Cortex-A series (multi-)core.

An A series multicore is made for processing like most PCs do or require, allowing you to use WinCE / Linux / Android almost exactly like on any other PC. However, some applications don't really suit an operating system.

While Cortex-M series processors are still more than powerful enough to run WinCE or Linux or possibly even Android, they are aimed more closely at "specific task" embedded work, where the software is made bare metal (i.e. no operating system).

A bare metal situation makes it a lot easier to gain control over execution time and resources, where having the OS layer in between, even if it's a real time OS, makes it a more complex thing to work with and on. Add to that the fact that lower speed M series processors are much cheaper than their A series cousins, when bought at the same quantities.

Of course, in many situations having an OS around is a nice thing, but for all intents and purposes I personally consider the Raspberry Pi (1, 2 or whatever version they go up to later) more as a "toy"/"consumer thing", as none of its externals, interfaces or main-line software development is remotely geared to reliable use as a professional test board.
The Experimenter boards elsewhere are generally designed by a well paid design team with semi-intimate knowledge of the processor, where RPi is made by enthusiast who make it for a specific purpose of being a lot like a Linux PC based on Datasheets.

#### Based entirely and solely on my experience with RPi 1, RPi2 may have changed some of this (but I left them already):

Add to that the general availability of full documentation of the processors on ST/TI/Atmel/Freescale/NXP boards, whereas the Broadcom is "a big mystery to all but the few core developers", because Broadcom makes you sign an NDA before you receive the complete and unlimited specifications and drivers, which often you don't even get to if you're not ordering 1000's.

Comment: A Cortex M part is really going to struggle with the overhead of running Windows embedded, Linux, or Android.

Comment: TI is a bit more secretive than Freescale, NXP, etc... and NVidia and Qualcomm are with Broadcom in the "everything under NDA" category.

Comment: @MattYoung Given it doesn't have an external memory controller, it would be just impossible. The only feasible choices would be uLinux, FreeRTOS and friends.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not impossible, just incredibly cumbersome, slow, and not worth doing.

Comment: Very good info, thank you. Especially the part about design and documentation.

Comment: I have had a somewhat hard time to gather the pieces of documentation on STM32. Unlike the others, who have a single Programming manual (and some APP notes) on  single web page, ST have chosen to tear all of the information apart and spread it around.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Fair enough, I'm not the greatest ST fan, for that reason. But at least it is still all there without ever having to let them know you exist. And just to annoy and irritate you, here's one of many Cortex-M's that do have external RAM: http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATSAMV71Q20.aspx?tab=documents :-P '(yah, yah, blah blah not GBytes) I wasn't saying "Download Debian, install", but you can run Linuxes and WinCE's on very, very many devices, be it stripped down or modified for purpose.